# How to generate where dynamically

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Hi I have these entities in my database.

```
public class Movie
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public ICollection<MovieTag> MovieTags { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<MovieTag> MovieTags { get; set; }
}

public class MovieTag
{
    public int MovieId { get; set; }
    public Movie Movie { get; set; }
    public int TagId { get; set; }
    public Tag Tag { get; set; }
}
```

I'm developing search funtion which, based on user input should search for tags and titles.
Code below works fine for tags, but I also want to check if there are movies when title contains all words from user input.

Let's in db I have movie with `Title = "test adventure movie" and with tag named = "adventure"`.

My query should return this movie for phrases like ex. `"adv"`, `"movie adventure"`, `"test movie"`

```
var phraseWords = phrase.Split(' ')
  .Where(x => x.Length > 1)
  .Select(x => x.Trim().ToLower())
  .Distinct()
  .ToList();

var results = _context.MoviesTags
                 .AsNoTracking()
                 .Include(x => x.Movies)
                 .Include(x => x.Tags)
                 .Where(x => phraseWords.Contains(x.Tag.Name.ToLower())
                 .Select(x => x.Movies)
                 .AsQueryable();
```

So far I've tried these 2 things and in both approaches EF throwed me an Exception, which says `The LINQ expression could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated...`

1. To use All() method:

```
.Where(x => phraseWords.Contains(x.Tag.Name.ToLower()) || phraseWords.All(y => x.Movies.Title.Contains(y)))
```

2. Dynamic linq library - to build function like this and join these statements:

   ```
    var titleStatements = string.Join(" && ", GetTitleStatements(phraseWords));
    var wordsFilter = $"x => phraseWords.Contains(x.Tag.Name.ToLower()) || ({titleStatements})";

    private IEnumerable<string> GetTitleStatements(List<string> words)
    {
        foreach (var word in words)
        {
            yield return @$"x.Movies.Title.ToLower().Contains(""word"")";
        }
    }
   ```

Do you have any other ideas?

I am using these packages:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.9" /> 
<PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL" Version="7.0.4" />
```

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework or Entity Framework Core?  And which version of either are you using?

Comment: These packages
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.9" />
<PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL" Version="7.0.4" />

Comment: `.AsNoTracking()` <-- Do you have an _evidence-based_ reason for using `AsNoTracking` - or do you think it's the _make-query-go-faster_ switch?

Comment: The second thing

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you want, but does `.Where(x => phraseWords.Any(w => x.Tag.Name.ToLower().Contains(w) || x.Movie.Title.ToLower().Contains(w))` work?

Comment: I want to filter for movies where: 
`Movie has tag which contains at least one of phrase words` OR `Movie title contains all words from phrase in any order`

Comment: OK, then does `.Where(x => phraseWords.Any(w => x.Tag.Name.ToLower().Contains(w)) || phraseWords.All(w => x.Movie.Title.ToLower().Contains(w)))` work?  Does it throw the *`LINQ expression could not be translated`* error?  Or is the exception fixed but the wrong result returned?  See e.g. this LINQ to Objects mockup that seems to work: https://dotnetfiddle.net/9KIfxg.

Answer (score 0):

Ok got the solution for approach with dynamic linq library. The problem was because this library is not able to use variables inside clause. I've changed
`phraseWords.Contains(x.Tag.Name.ToLower())` to dynamic chain of OR's.

This do the job for me.